# Email has problems with css and will not allow css in the same file

Tags: css

It's like when I try to send email to a customer and add my css, it will appear and show that there are errors, such as in the image.

[image]

I've also tried to add it to a link as it can retrieve it, but css does not work and it will not be displayed nicely in email for use.

How can I solve the small problem so I can send email to customers who are great?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showcasing the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it. Being able to copy the code helps us debug it much faster. Also, **what errors** are you having? For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email templates are very tricky and way behind in the CSS world. Sadly,  the best way to build them is to use tables.

I suggest you start with a template from Zurb and work your content into it. https://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates

I also suggest you leave those comment blocks out of it, the comment format you're using /** **/ is likely breaking your whole template.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, now I see where you're getting the comments from. using that syntax needs to be tested quite a bit. I suggest testing with a service like https://www.emailonacid.com which has a free plan that will show you how the email displays on different clients and browsers.